# delay() notification seems not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I am following this to delay notification. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#queueing-notifications

From localhost, I tried to send notification with Gmail credentials. It sends email but sends immediately and also it takes around 10 seconds to send email. My code is below.

```
$when = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);

$user->notify((new Notification($notification))->delay($when));
```

Was that due to Gmail or I missed something?

Comment: Did you set up queue? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues

Comment: Did you run  queue worker `php artisan queue:work` details here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#running-the-queue-worker

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a lengthy time period to try and answer this question but I had the same problem recently and the way I solved it is by implementing `ShouldQueue`

eg. In the App->Notifications->NotifyUser.php

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class NotifyUser extends Notification implements ShouldQueue {
use Queueable;
`}
```